# Is it preferred to put statements inside an else statement or use multiple else-if statements?

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested

Hopefully a simple question: I was just wondering if there was a convention for putting multiple statements inside an else, or using else-ifs. So, is it generally preferred to use an else statement with statements inside of it, like so:

```
if(r>0){

    return x;

} else {

    if(completed==false){

        return y;

    } else if(started==true){

        return z;

    } else{

        return xx;
    }}
```

or to use else ifs, like so:

```
if(r>0){

    return x;

} else if(completed==false){

    return y;

} else if(started==true){

        return z;

}else{

        return xx;

}
```

Comment: Primarily opinion based questions are off-topic here

Comment: I was wondering if there was a convention, therefore making it not opinion-based.

Comment: But if there is NOT, I'll delete it

Comment: What's up with the awful formatting? And your second example contains a syntax error.

Comment: Conventions (like coding standards) *are*, by definition, opinion based. Not all people agree with the same conventions.

Comment: @melpomene sorry, new to the website, struggling with writing code in this text editor, I'll be copy/pasting from VS in the future.

Comment: You had an opportunity to fix it _before_ hitting "submit", so that's no excuse.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit like, I made a mistake? I'm sorry? I'm new to the site? Everyone on here is just RUTHLESS it's ridiculous

Comment: @Allball103: You would be too if you, like us, had to put up with people doing this 10,000 times a day, instead of simply checking their work first. Basic due diligence.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What's actually wrong with it? There was an extra bracket and the format's bad, does that actually impact your ability to answer the question? I don't disagree that I could have fixed it but is it actually a big enough deal to you to warrant multiple comments instead of just a "check it before you submit next time"? People on this site complain about wasted time and then waste their time yelling at newbies, I see it on just about every question from someone with less than 100 reputation

Comment: @Allball103: I was addressing what you said to melpomene only. I have no idea what he thought was wrong with it; you will have to ask him. You are correct that it happens a lot with newbies - sadly most don't bother to read the formatting help or look at their post before submitting it. I don't see how being "new" is an excuse, frankly. Have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is primarily opinion-based. However, I believe this:

```
if (condition1) {
    // do stuff
}
else if (condition2) {
    // do stuff
} 
else { 
    // do stuff
}
```

is a lot easier to read and follow than the nested if-else blocks.

**Edit:**

As Porschiey pointed out below, switch statements are preferred to multiple if/else statements.

```
switch (condition) {
    case (a):
        // do something
    case (b):
        // do something else 
}
```

Comment: Multiple related if-blocks are better read and represented as as switch/case statements. This is why tools like Resharper or StyleCop usually recommend by default you represent them as such.